# How to get rid of the white border/background on my png image?

Tags: pygame, image, transparency, alpha-blending, png

I am making a game using pyGame; it is basically a space invader game, with a tank.

[image: Game screenshot showing forest scene with a tank sprite inside a white rectangle]

As we can see, this tank image I have has white borders / a white background, which I really want to get rid of.

I am thinking of editing it out, but it would be replaced by a different colour. Is there any way to somehow cut out this tank image from its original rectangular box?

Comment: Tip: a "boarder" is someone who is living in your home temporarily. A "border" is a line around the perimeter of a shape. What you have here though isn't just a white outline, the whole background of the sprite is white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a file format that supports alpha (png), an editor that can save it with a transparent background (gimp2, photoshop, basically not paint) and make sure you load the sprite [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059092/transparent-sprites-in-pygame)

Comment: I would like to add that even with all those done correctly, he can have this issue because of a simple mistake: many programs start with another layer which is a white background. Please make sure you remove / make it invisible before exporting.